# Php, wordpress (meta_box)

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код такого рода

```
array(
    'name' => 'Описание товара:',
    'id' => $prefix . 'des1',
    'desc' => 'Описание товара 1',
    'type' => 'text'
),
        array(
        'name' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'des2',
        'desc' => 'Описание товара 2',
        'type' => 'text'
    ),
```

На примере получается так как на фото:
[image: лучший сайт в мире]

А как сделать, чтобы array был один раз, а поля 2 с описанием товара?